# Homebrew linear PSU leakage current/voltage origin

Tags: power-supply, mains, linear-regulator, leakage-current

I made a 13.8V 10A linear power supply from a transformer took from a computer UPS whose battery was dead.
Now the issue is when I touch the output of the regulator leads, or the power supply casing I felt a slight tingling sensation. I measured the voltages using a multimeter with one lead referenced to earth and got these readings,

negative rail and earth = 34 VAC

positive rail and earth = 34VAC

Casing and earth = 15VAC

some parts of the transformer and earth =15VAC.

This stray voltage was interfering with my other circuits I'm testing. Fortunately I was able to solve the problem by earthing the case and the output rails directly, but I still
read a 1 to 2 Volts on my DMM.
How is this effect happening?
How do I get rid of this completely?
Also I can read a 700mV on a 1N4148 RF detector probe in the close proximity to my PSU when ever I touch it or attach a 10cm wire to it. Is it just static from all the switching devices in my house or does it have to do anything with the PSU.

Here is the schematic,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEZ5qj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sounds like inter-winding capacitance but really, you should post a schematic to be sure.

Comment: I have added the schematic. 
Lets assume its inter-winding capacitance, it cant be avoided, so how does one minimize the effects?

Comment: It's a bigger problem in switching power supplies because of the high frequencies involved but, it's also countered by the inter-capacitance being smaller. If "earth" is available and you can earth the DC output that is the easiest fix. If not, you will have to use non-electrolytic capacitors down to earth from the negative (and sometimes positive) DC output.

Comment: I'll try both, how much should the non-electrolytics be in value?
Also what do you think about the spooky readings on my rf pobe?

Comment: I can't comment on the RF probe but I'd start about 1 uF and see what happens.